# killed windows, trying to recover data through ubuntu

Tags: windows, hard-drive

windows got corrupted during a update, i am trying to access the data on the HDD to back it up to restore windows. the HDD is mounted already, but when i try and acces the HDD, it does not show any data. i tried to change the permissions to be able to view whats on the disk, but it does not let me. every time i change the permission and click apply, they change back to being blank. any info would help thank you. BTW i have Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Was it a Windows, or an Ubuntu update that caused the issue? Was Windows hibernated, or was the partition encrypted?

Comment: What are you running **Ubuntu** on, and how are you asking the (former) Windows hard drive? Is it external, or a second drive?